How to create code block for a text editor
I'm trying to add a new feature to my note app which is to add a code block.
This code block is actually a div tag with a classname that I will use, to style it and it will have the contenteditable="true".
There are two problems
First : when I press Enter, because of the contenteditable thing it creates a new div tag for me instead of moving to next line.
Second : I do not have a proper way of finding the position of i-coursor, my text is inside a p tag, not an input or textarea (because I want to have HTML elements in my note) so selectionStart and selectionEnd are not an option.
Please offer me a solution for finding i-coursor position as well as preventing default behavior of pressing Enter.
Look at the below image to understand what I want better:


Why you dont simply use a library for that like tinymce ? They have a very good documentation

it looks nice but when i delete my modal from DOM and try to re generate a new one tinymce wont work on that.

Do you run the javascript init code again? Like :
tinymce.init({ selector: '#mytextarea' });

yes i do , problem was fixed though , i shall not set an ID for my textarea it does not matter how i select it ( target or selector with className ) if it has an ID it will not work for a second time . than you for your suggestion this editor is life savor guess im gonna bloat my app with libraries from now on xd:).
